# jQuery $.ajax function works, but shorthand functions like $.get/$.getJSON do not - using jQuery 1.7.2 and Grails 2.1 and twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, twitter-bootstrap, grails-2.0

My first question here.

Has anybody had any problem with using shorthand functions for ajax requests?

This works:

```
('#book').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){
        return $.ajax({
            url: "/book/autocompleteBooks",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {queryString: query},
            success: function(results){
                typeahead.process(results);
            }
        });
    },
    property: "title",
    onselect: onSelectBook
});
```

But none of these two works:

```
('#book').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){
        return $.get({
            url: "/book/autocompleteBooks",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {queryString: query},
            success: function(results){
                typeahead.process(results);
            }
        });
    },
    property: "title",
    onselect: onSelectBook
});

('#book').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){
        return $.getJSON({
            url: "/book/autocompleteBooks",
            data: {queryString: query},
            success: function(results){
                typeahead.process(results);
            }
        });
    },
    property : "title",
    onselect: onSelectBook
});
```

The other thing is that replacing `url` with `createLink` does not work also.

```
url: "/book/autocompleteBooks"

url: "${createLink(controller: 'book', action: 'autocompleteBooks')}"
```

I'd rather use shorthand functions to make to code to be simplier to read and basically for aesthetics :)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any error messages? Is the request actually being made? Is there a response? etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Structure of `$.get()` is like:

```
$.get(
  "/book/autocompleteBooks",     // url
  {queryString: query},          // data
  function(data) {               // success
    // code
  },
  'json'                         // dataType
);
```

and `$.getJSON()` is:

```
$.getJSON(
     "/book/autocompleteBooks",   // url
     {queryString: query},        // data
     function(results){           // success
       // code
     }
);
```

Read more about ***[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)*** and ***[$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)***

Comment: Great. My silly mistake, I'll be more focused in the future. Thank you. I would vote but I'm not allowed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation of the two shorthand methods you are trying to use. They don't accept an object of options as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

$.get() id shorthand for $.ajax() method. But actually the syantaxfor $.get is like this

> $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
>    $('.result').html(data);
>   alert('Load was performed.');
>    });

where a $.ajax() is called as

> $.ajax({
>     url: url,
>    data: data,
>    success: success,
>        dataType:dataType });

for more info on $.get() refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/